# Can Xbox music deep links redirect to the windows 8 music player?

Tags: windows-8, hyperlink, xbox-music

I'm specifically working with Xbox music deep and the windows 8 music player, but I think this a more general question of redirection from browser to app.
I am building deep links to xbox music based on the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546675.aspx
When I click on a link like this: http://music.xbox.com/Track/768E1306-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933?action=play I would expect that if I am on windows 8 and have the music app installed it would go their rather than in the browser (or that it would redirect). At minimum I'd like to be able to open to the same browser window each time I click on a link. It looks like itunes does something closer to what I'd like by using a target="itunes_store" in the link (it opens in the browser but then asks to open the itunes app) but I don't see anything similar document by xbox music.

Here's what I'm seeing:

I can paste a link like the one above into IE's address bar (either desktop or the win8 app) and it will ask me if I want to open the music app, this also works if I click on the link within another windows8 app like the mail application or if I launch using Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync from my own windows 8 application.

However, if I click on the same link in a web page it brings up the web version of xbox music with the "Try Xbox Music" banner, which I can then click to bring me to the windows 8 application.  At that point IE seems to cache some state because any subsequent links that I click go directly to the web version without the banner, and furthermore pasting into the address bar or launching from another winodows8 application now brings me to the web version.  Closing down all instances of the browser gets me back to the original state.

The web version of the xbox music application is pretty slick, but I'd like to understand how to get application version to open consistently if at all possible.   Is there a different protocol for linking to content to be opened in a windows 8 application?  Is there a reason that I get a different behavior from a link typed into the address bar of IE vs. clicking on a link with the same URL (I played with target options, but didn’t find one that got me to the message to open the application).

Answer (score 1):

The link works fine for me on Windows 8. Are you sure you have the app installed properly?

Instead of putting it in a browser, you might try using a button and calling Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(yourUrl));

Alternatively, you might try using my Xbox.Music library on NuGet (http://www.nuget.org/packages/xbox.music), as I think it handles this for you.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks.  Based on your comments I updated the original question.  I had been assuming that the different behavior I was seeing was based on how I was getting to the link but it seems like there is something else more random going on.  When you say it works fine, does it bring you directly to the built in Music App?  I've reset file associations and tried this on a clean laptop and I've don't think I've seen that behavior ever.

Comment: When you say you tried it on a "clean laptop", have you opened up and actually used the built-in music app before clicking the link?

Comment: I tried both before and after my initial use of the built in music application.  I meant 'clean' in this instance to mean that I hadn't signed into xbox-music via the browser and hadn't fiddled with any file/protocol associations.

Comment: So, I just tried it on a fresh Windows 8.1 with Update install, before I had opened the Music app. The first time, it took me to the web streaming site, with a big banner at the top that said "download the app". After I did, then the link opened up in the app every time.

Comment: I think the problem is that the "built in" Music app does not have the proper file association for the link, but the updated Store version does. I don't think there is a way around this.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll spin up a VM machine today and see if I can reproduce your fresh windows 8.1 experience (I was obviously too sloppy with my 'clean' experience.

Comment: I spun up a fresh windows 8.1 + update VM and launched directly from a link within IE and still no joy. But after a bunch of iterations on trying to uninstall xbox music and download from the store I think I at least have the randomness figured out, but am still stuck on the original issue.  I've updated the post to reflect my new understanding.

Comment: I'll send this to the Xbox Music team and see if I can't get someone to respond for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the xbox music team has updated the deep link api to include a specific target attribute, which solves the problem.  By adding target=app to the link above I am consistently being redirected to the application.  So the 'fixed' version of my example url is:

http://music.xbox.com/Track/768E1306-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933?action=play&target=app